# Ruby seems to corrupt once a day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a Red Hat EL6 server (for production). I installed ruby and rubygems from source.

```
# uname -a
Linux servername 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 13 18:24:36 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-linux]
```

I'm able to deploy from my development machine to this production server. Everything works well. I come in next day, get the passenger error page. I forget what the error was, it happened last week. But I couldn't even run the command `ruby -v`.

I try to investigate what happened, I couldn't find the source of the error. So I compile Ruby and RubyGems (2.0.3) again. Everything works well again. I come in on Monday, get the passenger error page:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1070:in `require': closed stream (IOError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1070:in `<module:Gem>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:114:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

This time I can run the ruby commands such as `ruby -v` but I can't run `gem -v` because I will get the same error I got on the passenger page.

So I go to the rubygems.rb file, line 1070 to see the line of code that is generating the error and it's this one...

```
require "rubygems/specification"
```

So I go to the rubygems folder and there is a specification.rb file.

**UPDATE**
Ok, so I tried to install rubygems again and ran `ruby setup.rb` and this is what I got...

```
# ruby setup.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1070:in `require': closed stream (IOError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1070:in `<module:Gem>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:114:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

Does anybody have an idea of what's going on with the server? I'm going to try to compile rubygems again. It will probably fix the error but I suspect tomorrow I'll get another error.

Comment: Doing the same thing over again, without changing anything, is unlikely to have a different result or fix the problem. This sounds like it would be better asked on http://superuser.com.

Comment: Thanks! I'm installing Ruby 2.0.0p195 now, I'll see if the problem goes away. If it doesn't, I'll probably ask this question on superuser.com

Comment: I very seriously doubt it's a Ruby issue. It sounds like it happens periodically, not after running Ruby code, so I'd suspect a system task is messing with the disk or devices or processes, possibly changing permissions, which causes things to fall apart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prelink was messing the Rails app: http://www.tsheffler.com/blog/?p=491

> Two articles on the web suggested that the Linux prelink optimizer was actually corrupting the Ruby binary.  The solution is to tell the system to BAN prelinking on the Ruby binary.  After adding the '-b /usr/bin/ruby' line to the /etc/prelink.conf file as suggested, the problem seems to have gone away.

More info:

- http://www.improvingwetware.com/2011/04/07/strange-error-from-rubygems-due-to-linux-prelink-hellip
- http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/205897

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a long shot, but you don't have a full disc, do you?

Comment: What do you mean "a full disc"?

Comment: A disc that has no more storage space available.

Comment: it does have enough storage